# Check if Fiddler's AutoResponder is enabled via FiddlerScript

Tags: fiddler, auto-responder

Is it possible to check if AutoResponder is enabled using only FiddlerScript?

I have some code that modifies request headers, but I only want that code to fire when AutoResponder is on. I looked through the API but didn't see anything obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `FiddlerApplication.oAutoResponder.IsEnabled`

Comment: Thanks. For the answer and for the amazing product. You made my job A LOT easier